# How to check if reporting server is running?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I am working on a dashboard that shows whether a certain server is running.
I am left with 2 items, SSRS and Power BI. Is there any way through an SQL script to check if SSRS and PowerBI report server is active? Is there any system tables that stores that information?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pinging the urls of SSRS or Power BI reports and reportservice sites? These report servers cannot function without them.

Reports website - `http://<reportservername>/reports>`

Reports web service - `http://<reportservername/reportserver`